# ERROR: cannot launch node of type [...]: can't locate node [...] in package [...]

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This system is running Ubuntu 16.04 64bit with Kinetic. The project builds properly with `catkin_make`; and right after `source devel/setup.bash` is run in the same terminal. As soon as the project is launched via `roslaunch jimmy_lidar_motor_control lidar_motor_control.launch` the following error appears:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [jimmy_lidar_motor_control/lidar_motor_control]: can't locate node [lidar_motor_control] in package [jimmy_lidar_motor_control]
```

The project structure is pretty standard:

```
└── src
    ├── jimmycpp
    │   ├── //unrelated files (I think)
    │   ├── //unrelated files (I think)
    │   └── //unrelated files (I think)
    └── jimmy_lidar_motor_control
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── include
        │   └── jimmy_lidar_motor_control
        │       └── lidar_motor_control.h
        ├── launch
        │   └── lidar_motor_control.launch
        ├── msg
        │   └── motion_command_to_execute.msg
        ├── package.xml
        └── src
            └── lidar_motor_control.cpp
```

the launch file is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
    <node name="jimmy_lidar_motor_control_mynode" 
          pkg="jimmy_lidar_motor_control" 
          type="lidar_motor_control"
          output="screen"/>
 </launch>
```

To figure out what files ROS can "see" i ran rosrun command and pressed TAB-TAB, and all the files in the directory are visible:

```
mo@Home-W530:~/Desktop/workspace$ rosrun jimmy_lidar_motor_control 
CMakeLists.txt                  lidar_motor_control.launch
jimmy_lidar_motor_control_node  motion_command_to_execute.msg
lidar_motor_control.cpp         package.xml
lidar_motor_control.h
```

Everything is in C++ so I don't think it's related to file permissions (output of `ls -la`):

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mo mo 7287 Jan 19 12:32 lidar_motor_control.cpp
```

All the questions I looked through did not solve my issue:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/145801/cant-locate-node-in-package/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/291235/roslaunch-cant-locate-node-but-rosrun-works-fine/
- everything else that was relevent was really old (5 years or so)

Here is the CMakeLists.txt in case the issue is there:

```
# What version of CMake is needed?
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(jimmy_lidar_motor_control)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
   jimmycpp
  message_generation
)

#declare any custom files that I have created
add_message_files(
  FILES
  motion_command_to_execute.msg
)

#the custom message I am declaring relies on data types found here
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs )

catkin_package( 
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES my_robot_base
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp message_runtime
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

# Specify locations of header files.
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#  NOTE: executable name and source file name should be the same!!!!
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/lidar_motor_control.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node serial ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

# this line is to be used anytime I am using custom messages. It prevents build 
# errors when I run `catkin_make`. The first argument is the same name as the 
# name of the source file. The second argument is the name of the package plus 
# add “_generate_messages_cpp”. This solution to my problem is described on 
# http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B) in section
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
  ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
  ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
  jimmy_lidar_motor_control_generate_messages_cpp
)
```

in case the entire output of `roslaunch jimmy_lidar_motor_control lidar_motor_control.launch` which causes this problem is useful, here it is:

```
mo@Home-W530:~/Desktop/workspace$ roslaunch jimmy_lidar_motor_control lidar_motor_control.launch 
... logging to /home/mo/.ros/log/749beb5c-3ae5-11ea-9996-e09d3128cfa4/roslaunch-Home-W530-6823.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://Home-W530:37099/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /
    jimmy_lidar_motor_control_mynode (jimmy_lidar_motor_control/lidar_motor_control)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [6833]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 749beb5c-3ae5-11ea-9996-e09d3128cfa4
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6846]
started core service [/rosout]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [jimmy_lidar_motor_control/lidar_motor_control]: can't locate node [lidar_motor_control] in package [jimmy_lidar_motor_control]
^C[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

I tried everything i could find online and am stuck. If I can run any commands to shed more light, please let me know. Thank you  in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342053/error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5B...%5D:-can%27t-locate-node-%5B...%5D-in-package-%5B...%5D/) by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2020-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/lidar_motor_control.cpp)
```

Since your project name is "jimmy_lidar_motor_control", from:

```
project(jimmy_lidar_motor_control)
```

The node is going to be named "jimmy_lidar_motor_control_node", not "lidar_motor_control", which is why it's not found.

Also, not sure where this comes from:

```
#  NOTE: executable name and source file name should be the same!!!!
```

But that's totally false and wrong.

---

Originally posted by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) with karma: 641 on 2020-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on 2020-01-19**:
@christophebedard Thanks! I reworked  the `add_executable...` line (and everything that followed) and voila, everything worked! About the incorrect comment, thanks for pointing it out. I have a lot to learn, and I appreciate you pointing out a hole in my know-how... Thanks again!

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2020-01-20**:
It can be a good practice to give them the same name, but you don't *have* to. My pleasure!

**Comment by [kalkimann](https://answers.ros.org/users/78567/kalkimann/) on 2021-07-24**:
"reworked the add_executable... line (and everything that followed)"

what's the rework? please share.

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2021-07-26**:
@kalkimann I'm guessing they changed "lidar_motor_control" to "jimmy_lidar_motor_control_node", or "lidar_motor_control" to "${PROJET_NAME}_node". Just ask another question if these instructions don't apply well to your own situation/issue.